# Issue importing the Theano framework using Python

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, theano, mpich

Can't import theano. When I put this command in my terminal `python -c "import theano; print (theano.__version__)"` , this message shows up:

> [mpiexec@my-computer] match_arg (utils/args/args.c:159): unrecognized argument pmi_args
>
> [mpiexec@my-computer] HYDU_parse_array (utils/args/args.c:174): argument matching returned error
>
> [mpiexec@my-computer] parse_args (ui/mpich/utils.c:1596): error parsing input array
>
> [mpiexec@my-computer] HYD_uii_mpx_get_parameters (ui/mpich/utils.c:1648): unable to parse user arguments
>
> [mpiexec@my-computer] main (ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:153): error parsing parameters

This never happened before and I don't know how to fix it. I'm using an Anaconda's environment to execute the python code.

My Python/GCC version: 3.6.8 Intel Distribution; GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)]

My OS: Linux Mint 19.1 Xfce

P.S.: English isn't my first language, feel free to correct me, I'd appreciate that too :) .

Comment: If you create a different Conda env for Theano, does it still have this issue? E.g., `conda create -n test_theano python=3.6 theano`, then activate and run your test code. If it does work, perhaps comparing the two envs could be helpful in troubleshooting.  Also, did you recently update something in your env? Maybe have a look at `conda list --revisions` for recent changes in mpich, gcc, etc.

Comment: I was working on a different environment with intel distribution python, but then I find out that it was due to the mpich path, because I followed this tutorial https://www.bennettnotes.com/how-to-build-a-supercomputer/ to build a cluster using mpich and I changed the mpiexec and mpich path, so that was the issue, once I changed the .bashrc it worked normally!